# Why are the ellipses not being displayed in my Processing-Code?

Tags: java, for-loop, processing, drawing, ellipse

I have a question about my code in Processing. I'm trying to display weather data from past years and draw ellipses on the screen to create a graph. However, the ellipse is not being drawn. What could be the reason for this? The coordinates are valid and within the screen area. When I try to draw an ellipse with simple coordinates outside the loops, it works without any issues. That's why I believe it has something to do with the loops. I've shared my code here. It may not be executable as the API key is not valid, but perhaps someone can still assist me.

```
import http.requests.*;
import java.util.Calendar;


void setup()
{
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  
  
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  
  int d;
  int m;
  int y;
  
  int cols = 8;
  int rows = 11;
  
  float[][] temps = new float[cols][rows];
  
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    m= calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    d= calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    
    for (int p=0;p<11;p++)
    {
      calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
      y = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      String todate = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
      
      GetRequest get = new GetRequest("https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/Innsbruck/"+todate+"?unitGroup=metric&include=days&key=xxx&contentType=json");
      get.send();
      //println("Reponse Content: " + get.getContent());

      JSONObject response = parseJSONObject(get.getContent());
      float tempmax = response.getJSONArray("days").getJSONObject(0).getFloat("tempmax");
      //println(d+"."+m+"."+y+": Maxtemp - "+tempmax);
      
      temps[i][p]=tempmax;
      
      
      float pointx = width-width/10-width/10*i;
      float pointy = height/2+tempmax*10;
      
      println(pointx + ", " + pointy);
      fill(255);
      ellipse(pointx,pointy,5,5);
    }
  }
  
}

void draw()
{
  
}
```

Comment: there is no code in your question that draws an ellipse

Comment: ellipse(pointx,pointy,5,5);

Comment: Yes, the output is valid and the coordinates are within the screen area.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things happening at the same time and it will be easier to break down the program into simpler steps and tackle them one at a time.

For example:

1. Your code is using the Visualcrossing Weather API. You're using `xxx` as a placeholder for where the API key should be. That's perfectly fine when sharing code online. You need to keep that key private: just make sure you replace xxx with your actual Visualcrossing API Key when running the code locally.
2. Your code is using two nested for loops which will result in 8 x 11 requests to be made *instantly* every single time you run the sketch. Usually Web API have a rate limit: you can not call them multiple times in very short bursts. You could split your program into two: one that requests the 88 weather data points and caches the data to a local .json file that you can use later; a sketch that simply loads the local .json file and visualised the data as you see fit. (This way you won't get blocked by API and you can iterate/try as many versions of visualising as you'd like using cached data.)
3. It's unclear how you want to map the data into the API and back from the API. Maybe the `i` loop (from 0 to 8) is meant to be 0 to 7 days and `p` (from 0 to 11) represents months so you'd get the maximum temperature for each day in a single week, one month at a time ? There is confusion over `m` since you always set it to `m= calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;`.(Similarly the `p` counter is not used to increment the dates).

Here are a few hopefully helping bits of info for each section.

**API Key error**
When I run your code I get this error in Processing's Console:

```java
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'
    at processing.data.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:255)
    at processing.data.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:239)
    at processing.core.PApplet.parseJSONObject(PApplet.java:5377)
    at sketch_231003b.setup(sketch_231003b.java:59)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2051)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$9.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1386)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:356)
NullPointerException
```

This simply means the `xxx` API is incorrect and in your code you need to use your actual API Key. (Please don't share that publicly online).

One typical way of handling this is to set the API key as an environment variable (e.g. `MY_API_KEY=#######` then in Processing you'd use `System.getenv('MY_API_KEY')` to retrieve the value). If you're not familiar with setting up environment variables don't worry about it: hardcoding the key for now will do. Just be careful who you share that code with :)

**Caching data**

You already make a query and parse the response here:

```
GetRequest get = new GetRequest("https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/Innsbruck/"+todate+"?unitGroup=metric&include=days&key=xxx&contentType=json");
get.send();
JSONObject response = parseJSONObject(get.getContent());
```

You can use a `JSONArray`(https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html) to store your data.
Here's an example based on your code:

```java
import http.requests.*;
import java.util.Calendar;


void setup()
{
  background(0);
  
  String API_KEY = "PLACE_YOUR_WEATHER_API_KEY_HERE";
  // prepare JSONArray to cache Weather API data
  JSONArray weatherAPIData = new JSONArray(); 
  // counter for each API call / data entry
  int weatherAPICounter = 0;
  
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  
  int d;
  int m;
  int y;
  
  int cols = 8;
  int rows = 11;
  int total = rows * cols;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
  {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    m = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    
    for (int p = 0; p < rows; p++)
    {
      calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
      y = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      String todate = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
      println("requesting", todate, weatherAPICounter+1, "of", total);
      GetRequest get = new GetRequest("https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/Innsbruck/" + todate + "?unitGroup=metric&include=days&key=" + API_KEY + "&contentType=json");
      get.send();
      println("Reponse Content: " + get.getContent());

      JSONObject response = parseJSONObject(get.getContent());
      // cache the API data into RAM
      weatherAPIData.setJSONObject(weatherAPICounter, response);
      // increment data counter
      weatherAPICounter++;
      // wait 1s in between calls (to avoid API rate limits)
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  
  // persist the API data cache to disk
  saveJSONArray(weatherAPIData, "data/weather-api-data.json");
  
  println("cached saved to the data folder");
  exit();
}
```

As mentioned above the date mapping process is unclear. Currently it requests data years which the API doesn't seem to support:

```java
Reponse Content: Bad API Request:Invalid year requested. Years must be between 1950 and 2050
java.lang.RuntimeException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'
    at processing.data.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:255)
    at processing.data.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:239)
    at processing.core.PApplet.parseJSONObject(PApplet.java:5377)
    at JSONAPICache.setup(JSONAPICache.java:61)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2051)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$9.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1386)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:356)
```

(Bare in mind the [weather API documentation](https://www.visualcrossing.com/resources/documentation/weather-api/timeline-weather-api/) mentions a few other endpoints. Depending on what data you're after there could an option to query the data you're after in a single (or less calls))

Once you have this data you can write a separate sketch that loads it and renders ellipses based on the mapped `maxtemp` data. Remember to drag and drop the weather-api-data.json file from the sketch above into the new sketch:

```java
void setup()
{
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  
  
  int cols = 8;
  int rows = 11;
  
  // load cached data
  JSONArray weatherAPIData = loadJSONArray("data/weather-api-data.json");
  // counter for each API call / data entry
  int weatherAPICounter = 0;
  
  
  for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
  {
    for (int p = 0; p < rows; p++)
    {
      // try to get each request (and handle errors)
      try {
        
        JSONObject response = weatherAPIData.getJSONObject(weatherAPICounter);
        float tempmax = response.getJSONArray("days").getJSONObject(0).getFloat("tempmax");
        
        float pointx = width-width/10-width/10*i;
        float pointy = height/2+tempmax*10;
        
        println(pointx + ", " + pointy);
        ellipse(pointx,pointy,5,5);
        
      
      } catch(Exception e){
        println("encountered null data index", weatherAPICounter);
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      
      // increment JSONArray counter 
      weatherAPICounter++;
    }
  }
  
}
```

(You might also find the `map()`(https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) function handy to remap the `maxtemp` data).

Good luck debugging and have fun visualising data.